# The system cannot find the path specified when I run npm start command in visual code studio

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, js-ipfs

Whenever I run the command npm start I got below error. Please, help regarding this.

The system cannot find the path specified.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! example-browser-browserify@1.0.0 build: `copyfiles -u 1 -a './public/**/*' './dist' && browserify ./src/index.js >  ./dist/bundle.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the example-browser-browserify@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yash mudgal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-02T18_28_25_719Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! example-browser-browserify@1.0.0 start: `npm run build && npm run serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the example-browser-browserify@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yash mudgal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-02T18_28_25_795Z-debug.log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.